# Create yellow non-shimmering potion

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

In a Minecraft Forge mod, I want to create a portion that appears yellow and doesn't shimmer (like a yellow version of the "Water Bottle" potion).

I'm currently doing something like this (irrelevant bits omitted):

```
@Mod(modid=modId, name="Lemonade Mod", version="1.0")
public class LemonadeMod {
    ...
    private static final Potion POTION_LEMONADE = new PotionHealth(false, 0xFF_FF_FF_55);
    private static final PotionType POTION_TYPE_LEMONADE = new PotionType("lemonade", new PotionEffect(POTION_LEMONADE));
    ...    
    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber
    public static class RegistrationHandler {    
        @SubscribeEvent
        public static void registerPotionTypes(RegistryEvent.Register<PotionType> event) {
            event.getRegistry().register(POTION_TYPE_LEMONADE.setRegistryName("lemonade"));
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a yellow potion, but it shimmers. Is there a way to remove the shimmering effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on responses from a [Minecraft Forge forum post](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/65262-custom-potion-that-is-yellow-and-doesnt-shimmer), this class defines an Item that behaves like a potion when you right-click:

```
import net.minecraft.client.util.ITooltipFlag;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.item.EnumAction;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.util.ActionResult;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumActionResult;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemLemonade extends Item {

    /**
     * This method needs to be overridden because otherwise the duration is too short,
     * the potion consumption won't animate correctly, and there won't be any sound
     */
    @Override
    public int getMaxItemUseDuration(ItemStack stack)
    {
        return 32;
    }

    @Override
    public EnumAction getItemUseAction(ItemStack stack) {
        return EnumAction.DRINK;
    }

    @Override
    public ActionResult<ItemStack> onItemRightClick(World worldIn, EntityPlayer playerIn, EnumHand handIn) {
        playerIn.setActiveHand(handIn);
        return new ActionResult<>(EnumActionResult.SUCCESS, playerIn.getHeldItem(handIn));
    }

    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    @Override
    public void addInformation(ItemStack stack, @Nullable World worldIn, List<String> tooltip, ITooltipFlag flagIn) {
        tooltip.add("Delicious, refreshing lemonade");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the systems vanilla has for brewing potions:

> [Diesieben07](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/65262-custom-potion-that-is-yellow-and-doesnt-shimmer/?do=findComment&comment=310181) said:
>   `PotionType` is a potion that can be brewed, `Potion` is just the "type of effect."

With info from that thread, just create a normal item class and override this method, like this:

```
@Override
public EnumAction getItemUseAction(ItemStack stack)
{
    return EnumAction.DRINK;
}
```

This deals with the shimmer, as `ItemPotion` overrides `public boolean hasEffect(ItemStack stack)` to return true when the potion has any effects (and you don't want that).

Then all you have to do is give the `PotionEffect` to the player when they drink your item by overriding `onItemUseFinish`. You can look at `ItemPotion` for an example of how to do this (although there will be large sections of code you won't need).

Comment: PotionType and Potion aren't items, although there is an ItemPotion class. It's not clear to me how to instantiate an ItemPotion with the desired PotionType

Comment: You will need to create your own class that extends ItemPotion.

Comment: If I create a subclass of ItemPotion (e.g., ItemPotionLemonade), how do I associate my ItemPotionLemonade class with a PotionType or PotionEffect or Potion? (If you update your answer, with the info, I can accept it.)

Comment: @LorinHochstein Looks like you found an answer on the Forge forums before I could look into this some more; I'll go ahead and update this answer with the information from there.